2017 Community Moderator Election Results
Bitcoin's first moderator election has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:
   
They'll be replacing the pro tempore moderators shortly - please thank both crews for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with the new crew as they learn the ropes!
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here, or view a summary report online.

Congrats to all of you :)

Congratulations guys, and thanks for volunteering!
